# ZF2 Validator Context when using a Fieldset or Collection

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-validate

Is it possible to pass the full form as the context to a validator?

I would like to create a conditional validator for element X in fieldset A which checks the value of element Y in a different fieldset B.

The problem is that the isValid function only receives the context for the fieldset it is in. This element X knows nothing about element Y.

All answers greatly received!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with collections and ZendCollectionInputFilter yeah.

There's not like loads of documentation for this, know the zend guys are sorting this out though (think the only mention of it is in http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.2/classes/Zend.InputFilter.CollectionInputFilter.html) but for now a resource that really helped me was this:

http://www.aronkerr.com/2013/11/zf2-form-collection-validation-unique.html

Very clever stuff once you get your head round these. Can't really give you much more help as your question isn't massively specific and there is no code for your form, fieldsets and input filters that you currently have implmented but hope this helps. If you get stuck at any point more than happy to run through more specific code

Comment: Thanks @Jon - That guide was just what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Let's say our fieldsets A and B belong to the form `Sample`. We need to add the validators from this parent form in order to access the context of this form when validating any child fieldsets:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;

class Sample extends Form InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->add([
            'type' => 'App:Fieldset:A',
            'name' => 'fieldsetA',
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'type' => 'App:Fieldset:B',
            'name' => 'fieldsetB',
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'type' => 'submit',
            'name' => 'submit',

            'attributes' => [
                'value' => 'Submit',
            ],
        ]);
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return [
            'fieldsetA' => [
                'type' => 'InputFilter',

                'X' => [
                    'required' => true,
                    'allow_empty' => true,
                    'continue_if_empty' => true,

                    'validators' => [
                        [
                            'name' => 'Callback',
                            'options' => [
                                'callback' => function ($value)
                                {
                                    if ($this->data['fieldsetB']['Y'])
                                    {
                                        // do something
                                    }
                                    // do something else
                                },
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Notice how we add validators to X in A from within `Sample` using the `InputFilter` type. Next we access `$this->data` directly and traverse it to get Y in B.